# How to avoid writing duplicate queries when needing counts and then items

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have constructed a LINQ query that joins about a half dozen tables.  The problem is, for paging purposes, I want to get a count first of how many items will be returned.  So the issue I'm running into is having to write the exact same query twice: one to get the item count then another to build my collection of items.

Example:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var items = from i in context.Table1
                join a in context.TableA on i.SomeProperty equals a.SomeProperty
                join b in context.TableB on i.SomeOtherProperty equals b.SomeProperty
                join c in context.TableC on i.AnotherProperty equals c.SomeProperty
                etc.
                etc.
                select i;

    count = items.Count();
}   

return count;

.
.
.

using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var items = from i in context.Table1
                join a in context.TableA on i.SomeProperty equals a.SomeProperty
                join b in context.TableB on i.SomeOtherProperty equals b.SomeProperty
                join c in context.TableC on i.AnotherProperty equals c.SomeProperty
                etc.
                etc.
                select new
                {
                    DynamicProp1 = i.SomeProperty,
                    DyanmicProp2 = a.SomeProperty,
                    DyanmicProp3 = b.SomePropery,
                    etc.
                    etc.
                }
    ... do some stuff with 'items'...
}
```

I cannot think of any way to avoid this duplicate query.  I need access to all the joined tables in order to build my collection.  I would appreciate any tips or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create method which get context and return IQueryable of items with all needed entities:

```
class Holder
{
  TableAItem A{get;set;}
  TableBItem B{get;set;}
  ...
}

IQueryable<Holder> GetQuery(DbContext context)
{
  return from i in context.Table1
         join a in context.TableA on i.SomeProperty equals a.SomeProperty
         join b in context.TableB on i.SomeOtherProperty equals b.SomeProperty
         join c in context.TableC on i.AnotherProperty equals c.SomeProperty
         ...
         select new Holder
         {
           A = i,
           B = b
           ....
         };
}

using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var items = GetQuery(context);

    count = items.Count();
}   

return count;


using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var items = from r in GetQuery(context)
                select new
                {
                    DynamicProp1 = r.a.SomeProperty,
                    DyanmicProp2 = r.a.SomeProperty,
                    DyanmicProp3 = r.b.SomePropery,
                    etc.
                    etc.
                }
    ... do some stuff with 'items'...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that making a query doesn't execute it, this is called deferred execution. So why not make the query and then pass it around as an `IQueryable<>` object. For example, consider this code:

Just a simple method to return the last char from a string, but it also writes out what it's doing:

```
public char GetLastChar(string input)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetLastChar from {0}", input);
    return input.Last();
}
```

Now this code using the method:

```
var listOfStuff = new List<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3" };

Console.WriteLine("Making the query");

var results = from s in listOfStuff
              select GetLastChar(s);

Console.WriteLine("Before getting count");
var count = results.Count();
Console.WriteLine("Now enumerating the query");

foreach(var s in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

You will see the output as follows:

```
Making the query
Before getting count
GetLastChar from string1
GetLastChar from string2
GetLastChar from string3
3
Now enumerating the query
GetLastChar from string1
1
GetLastChar from string2
2
GetLastChar from string3
3
```